# React Render Master and Detail on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

I'm having a little trouble wrapping my head around the routing issue here.
I'm trying to get the details to render on the same page, but all I get is a blank page and the URL shows in the navigation bar.

**Goal**: Click the master on the left, render the detail on the right
[image: I want to render the details component here]

Here is my code:

**JournalDetail.jsx**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link, Route, Routes, useParams, useRouteMatch, generatePath } from "react-router-dom";
import { appVariables } from "../../components/AppVariables";
import { format } from 'date-fns';
import { parseISO } from 'date-fns';

import JournalDetails from './JournalDetails';


const JournalDetail = () => {

    const { id } = useParams();
    const [isLoadingData, setisLoadingData] = useState(true);
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [showData, setShowData] = useState(false);
    

    useEffect(() => {
        setisLoadingData(true);
        fetchData();
        
    }, []);

    
    return (

        <div>
            {isLoadingData ? (
                    <h1>LOADING DATA........</h1>
                ) : (
                    
                    <div>
                        <h1>{data.JournalName} </h1>
                        <p>{data.JournalDescription}</p>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-12 col-md-12 col-xl-4 col-left">
                                <div className="mb-4">
                                    <div className="xxxcard-body">
                                        {renderChildren()}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-12 col-md-12 col-xl-8 col-right">
                                <div className="card mb-4">
                                    <div className="card-body">
                                        <div className="journal-details">
                                            <Routes>
                                                <Route path='/journal-details/:id' element={<JournalDetails />} />
                                            </Routes>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                        
                    
                    )
            
            }
        </div>
        
    );
    
    function fetchData() {

        fetch(appVariables.API_URL + 'Journal/' + id,
            {
                mode: "cors",
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((json) => {


                setisLoadingData(false);
                setData(json.Entity);

            }).catch((error) => console.log(error));

    }
    function renderChildren() {

        return (
            <div className="col-12 list" data-check-all="checkAll">

                {data.JournalEntries.map((ent) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="card d-flex flex-row mb-3 active" key={ent.JournalEntryId}>
                            <div className="d-flex flex-grow-1 min-width-zero">
                                <div className="card-body align-self-center d-flex flex-column flex-md-row justify-content-between min-width-zero align-items-md-center">

                                    <Link className="list-item-heading mb-0 truncate w-40 w-xs-100" to={generatePath('/journal-details/:id', { id: ent.JournalEntryId })}>
                                        {
                                            prettyDate(ent.EntryDate)
                                        }
                                    </Link>
                                    <p className="mb-0 text-muted text-small w-15 w-xs-100">{ent.EntryBy}</p>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    );//ats-237372
                })}

            </div>
        )

    }
    function renderDetail(id) {

        return (<div><h2>Test-Detail - {id}</h2></div>);
    }
    function prettyDate(date) {

        const uglyDate = new Date(date);
        const formattedDate = uglyDate.toLocaleDateString("en-us", {
            month: "short",
            day: "numeric",
            year: "numeric"
        })
        return formattedDate;
    }
};
export default JournalDetail;
```

**JournalDetails.jsx**

```js
import React from "react";
import { Link, useHistory, useParams } from "react-router-dom";


const JournalDetailComponent = () => {

    //  const { url } = useRouteMatch();
    const { id } = useParams();

    return (
        
        <div>
            <h2>Details - {id}</h2>
            </div>

        )
};
export default JournalDetailComponent;
```

**AppRoutes.js**

```js
    import { Counter } from "./components/Counter";
    import { FetchData } from "./components/FetchData";
    import { Home } from "./components/Home";
    import { Journal } from "./components/Journal";


    // Core Components/views
    import JournalDetail from "./pages/Journal/JournalDetail"


    const AppRoutes = [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <Home />
      },
      {
        path: '/counter',
        element: <Counter />
      },
      {
        path: '/fetch-data',
        element: <FetchData />
        },
        {
            path: '/journals',
            element: <Journal />
        },
        {
            path: '/journal-detail/:id',
            element: <JournalDetail />
        }
    ];

    export default AppRoutes;
```

**App.jsx**

```js
    import React, { Component, Suspense } from 'react';
    import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
    import AppRoutes from './AppRoutes';
    import { Layout } from './components/Layout';
    //import './custom.css';
    import { styled, createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';




    export default class App extends Component {
      static displayName = App.name;

      render() {
        return (
          <Layout>
            <Routes>
              {AppRoutes.map((route, index, component) => {
                const { element, ...rest } = route;
                return <Route key={index} {...rest} element={element} />;
              })}
            </Routes>
          </Layout>
        );
      }
    }
```

**Result**

[image]

[Here is a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-routingissue-xmnlj9?file=/src/components/Journal.jsx) demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Try `path=":id"` in your route instead for a relative route, this might be a parent routing issue or something? Hard to know for sure without seeing the entire routing scheme.

Comment: Thank you. No luck.  I will update with the entire routing scheme.

Comment: Which version of react-router are you using?

Comment: In one place you have `/journal-detail/:id` and another is `/journal-details/:id` with an `s` at the end, is that intentional?

Comment: Working theory is that you're passing `component` instead of `element` here.

Comment: Good catch. Yes that's intentional (for now). I wouldn't normally name that way. This is just an exercise.  I'll explore the component theory.  I appreciate your time!

Comment: I'm using react-router 6.3. I've seen the changes from < 6 versions. There is something that I'm not getting with regards to routing.  It seems straightforward, but then things dont work the way Im expecting them to.

Comment: `JournalDetail` is using the wrong `Route` prop to render the routed element, it should be `element` and not `component`. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Comment: Hi Drew, I hope this doesnt get closed as your suggestion didnt solve the issue. I changed the component prop to element and no change. I also changed the property value and still no change.  I'm going to post what renders in hopes to give more perspective.

Comment: Could you try creating a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: @DrewReese Here it is.  I added the full routing. There maybe an issue farther up the chain I am missing: https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-routingissue-xmnlj9?file=/src/components/Journal.jsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JournalDetail` renders descendent routes, so the parent route should be configured with a trailing wildcard matcher, or splat, `"*"` to allow all descendent routes to also be matched and rendered.

```
{
  path: "/journal-detail/:id/*",
  element: <JournalDetail />
}
```

Descendent routes build relative to the parent route, so since you want this other content to also render when the route path is `"/journal-detail/:id"` you'll the descendent route on `"/"`, e.g. the "parent route path".

```
const JournalDetail = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [isLoadingData, setisLoadingData] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [showDetail, setShowDetail] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setisLoadingData(true);
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {isLoadingData ? (
        <h1>LOADING DATA........</h1>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <h1>{data.JournalName} </h1>
          <p>{data.JournalDescription}</p>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12 col-md-12 col-xl-4 col-left">
              <div className="mb-4">
                <div className="xxxcard-body">{renderChildren()}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-12 col-md-12 col-xl-8 col-right">
              <div className="card mb-4">
                <div className="card-body">
                  <div>
                    <Routes>
                      <Route
                        path="/"
                        element={<JournalDetails />}
                      />
                    </Routes>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );

  ...
};
```

[image]

[image: Edit react-render-master-and-detail-on-the-same-page]

Comment: Hi Drew, Thank you for the detailed answer.  Conceptually it is getting clearer to me. The problem still remains on the click event. Reproducing: Making the two changes you suggested renders the first record in the detail box.  clicking on a link to the left causes a redirect to a blank page.

Comment: @CodeInColor There was a typo your links in the `JournalDetail` component where it was trying to link to `/journal-details/:id"` instead of `"/journal-detail/:id"`. Do you see the difference where the first was pluralized? I've updated the sandbox code, so please do check again when you've a chance.

Comment: @CodeInColor Welcome, glad to help. Cheers and good luck!